# Start autocomplete with special characther

Tags: jquery, primefaces

I want to initiate Autocomplete with a special character.
e.g @ or +

if a user types @ or + then it starts the autocomplete.
How do i do that using primefaces autocomplete /texarea?
Thanks

Comment: Are you running at least Primefaces v3.3? I know this was an issue in v3.2.

Comment: I actually want this feature. I am using v3.4 . i want to start the autocomplete with a special character. @jornak

Comment: This is a 10-line (if that) JavaScript/RegEx problem, but not something I'd expect someone to allow for in a big-giant-UI-framework.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#text_area_id').keyup( function(){
    var $_this = $(this), //this is js dom object $_this is jquery object
    atOrPlusCheck = $_this.val().match(/[@+]/g); //returns null if no matches

    if(atOrPlusCheck){
        someAutoCompleteFunction(this);
    }
} );
```

Can't help you with primefaces. Also, I tend to prefer keyup but somebody could hold '@' down and the event wouldn't fire until they let go of the key. so it would be '@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@<autocomplete>' which might not be a problem.

You could use keydown but then you're repeatedly hammering away at the event handler which could get messy.

Comment: Thanks I will try this out and see how i can fiddle with this for primefaces